# How to manipulate ASCII encoded text contained within a binary formatted file

Tags: c#

Background:

My assemblies strings are obfuscated using only ASCII characters. My logger outputs it's log files in a binary format. The log files contain much data in addition to the obfuscated strings. I can de-obfuscate strings.I need to keep the log file in it's original formatting but with the de-obfuscated strings

Task:

I need to read the binary log file and write to a new log file until I hit a length of ASCII characters. I then convert those characters to a string, de-obfuscate the string, send the new string to the binary writer and then carry on from the end of the ASCII character string reading/writing until I hit a new ASCII character string and then do it all again.

1. Is this possible?
2. I would appreciate some code in C# please if it is.
3. If my task methodology is flawed, is there an alternative?

Comment: there is nothing can't be done since it is only manipulating stream with encoding and doing some sort of encryption/decryption. But unless you have written some code and find a problem that you can't solve, other people can't just **imagine** what's the problem and post some code and say "hey, look at this, it can solve your problem even though you didn't mention what it was".

Comment: Ok Kennyzyx, 1 = yes, 2 = can't be bothered and 3 = not flawed and there are numerous alternatives. how do I recognize the first ascii character and the last ascii character in that sequence

Comment: Do you know (have the source) how the logger outputs the log file? Does it write down some marks, like some recognizable byte sequences to indicate the start and the end of obfuscated strings?

Comment: As the log program can generate a comma delimited text file of each 'field' in the binary file, I guess there must be. I've contacted the authors and will update asap.

Comment: The binary file contained a 'packet' for each log entry. That packet contained several fields that included the obfuscated text. The fields are segregated and using supplied SDK's I have managed to achieve the desired results. Thanks to kennyzx for his pointing me in the right direction.